# How to join two files in Linux for example if i have many files

Tags: merge, text-files

I have 133 files named as Trace1.log Trace2.log and so on so how can I merge all these files together and save it in one

Comment: `cat *.log >> everything.log`

Answer (score 9):

To simply concatenate the files in alphabetical order,

```
cat Trace*.log >combined
```

Take care to name the destination file so it doesn't match the wildcard, or you will get weird results.

Alphabetical order means Trace10.log sorts before Trace2.log. If you need them in numeric order, use a more suitable naming convention (e.g. rename Trace1.log to Trace001.log, etc) or use multiple wildcards;

```
cat Trace?.log Trace??.log Trace???.log >combined
```

The locale will affect what exactly "alphabetic order" means; these guidelines apply to the traditional C locale and English-language locales at least (and most other Western languages).

Comment: gotta love the power and simplicity of POSIX

Answer (score 3):

You can try using the cat command.

```
$ cat Trace* > TraceFull.log
```

Take a look at this site [Joining files together](http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/OSTut/Joining_files_together.html)

Answer (score 1):

if you're on a unix based system use the following command:

```
cat Trace*.log > TraceMerged.log
```

(while in the directory holding the logs)